# CONVERT and CAST to create a flat view - can't convert nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I am creating views to cast `varchar` as numeric (say a field `vw_number`) and date to convert to a US (101) style, i.e. mm/dd/yyyy (field `dt_view`).

The view is created fine and the data looks good, but when I use these fields to filter data it doesn't work.

```sql
select * from view where vw_number = 20
```

Throws an error:

> can't convert nvarchar to numeric.

```sql
select * from view where dt_view >= '10/01/2019'
```

Query runs fine but doesn't work as expected. `dt_view` is a date field in the table.

Comment: if you select * from the view without filter does it throw the same error? It may indicate that there is some data in that field that SQL Server can't convert to numeric.

Comment: The error is telling you the issue, you have some data in that column which doesn't convert to a number. Use `try convert` to identify the row in question.

Comment: What does "doesn't work as expected" mean? Maybe because you're using an ambiguous date format?

Comment: doesn't filter the data when one of those dates is used for filtering views. For instance, after creating view, I query the view to filter the data using that select * from vw where dt_view >= '05/01/2019'; this doesn't filter correctly. The issue seems to be with using date when after being converted using convert(varchar(10),dt_view,101).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from view where CAST(vw_number AS INT) = 20 -- cast to int

select * from view where dt_view >= '20191001' -- just to avoid locale problems
```

Of course the cast will fail if you have non-numeric data.

To find non-numerics try

```
select * from view where vm_number not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: `where CAST(vw_number AS INT) = 20` is the same as `where vw_number = 20`, since SQL Server will attempt to implicitly cast `vw_number` to int... second statement is good, though. BTW, `-123` is a valid int, and `0.43e-5` is a valid float. better use `try_cast`.

Comment: The OP asked about using cast, so I complied.  I try to adhere to the"explicit is better than implicit" rule. As for the rest though I use the simple query to find non-numerics even if I get a few false positives.  I can live with that.  I think its reasonable that a column called vw_number is likely an int.  So we can probably rule out floats and other numerics.  Still it would be better if the OP told us so.